# Dynamically resize font to fill up RichTextbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How do i dynamically resize the text in a RichTextbox so that it fills up the entire rich textbox?
any help is much appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate that what do you mean by "FILL" the textbox ? Put up some screenshot using Notepad or MS WORD to justify

Comment: I need for the text to take up the entire Textbox without leaving any space.

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN article almost answers your question. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986765.aspx.
You may download the attached sample there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to get creative with the 'Font' constructor. For example, on a click event then construct a new Font using some relationship with your application (or textbox size) with the desired font size.

```
Protected Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
  Dim yourfontsize As Integer    

  'machinery to create desired font size
  If blah then 
      yourfontsize = X() 
  Else
      yourfontsize = Y()
  End If


  yourtextbox.SelectionFont = New Font("Tahoma", yourfontsize, FontStyle.Bold)

End Sub
```

Where X() and Y() are functions to return your target font sizes based on whatever else may
be going on within your application.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh8963yx.aspx

Hope that helps!

-sf

Comment: It appears that the font size needs to be calculated dynamically based on the RichTextBox size. Your example shows how to give a set font size.

Comment: Ah, I should have specified that X and Y could be functions dependent on other parts of his code rather than constants. I was merely trying to point him to the font constructor, I leave the math to him. I have edited the original post to reflect this.